# invoke def method like class in groovy?

Tags: function, class, groovy

How could I invoke def like class?

For example I invoke class

```
class object{do things}
new object ()
```

How could I do with

```
def object {}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**def** can be specified as the type of a variable or the return type of a method.  For example:
To use **def** a as a method return type:

```
class Fun {
 def haveFun() {
   return "fun";
}
```

You would invoke getFun method like any method:

```
new Fun().haveFun();
```

To use **def** as a variable type declaration:

```
def fun = "fun"
```